# Sort by posts that have a featured image?

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, sort

I'd like to sort posts on the index page to show those that have a featured image first.

I've done this in functions.php:

```
   add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

   function my_get_posts( $query ) {
     if ( is_home() || is_archive() ) {
       $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
       $query->set('meta_key', '_wp_attached_file');
     }
   }
```

The causes no posts to be shown on the index page.

What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 1):

Change `_wp_attached_file` to `_thumbnail_id`

Comment: Close!  With this, *only* posts that have a thumbnail show up.  I'd like all posts to be listed, but those with a thumbnail to be listed first.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't query posts that both do & don't have a meta key - it's the nature of the join coupled with the schema. You'll have to run two queries, one for all *with*, the other *without*.

Comment: no outer joins?

Comment: You'll have to ask an SQL guru, but I'm pretty sure it can't be done (at least efficiently) with the design of metadata tables.